# How to get github webhook payload value in Jenkins job

Tags: github, jenkins, webhooks

I've GitHub repository called '**testProject**' - I have configured **`webhook`** for this repository - whenever any code commits to this repository - Jenkins job will trigger automatically. Its working as expected, but I want few values while trigger Jenkins job. For example:

I'm doing some code change and while committing I'm giving some commit message like this: `git commit -m "Enables Web service logic"`

I'm having this commit message as part of *GitHub web-hook payload* - But I want this message in my Jenkins message while triggering - How can I get this message?

Comment: Since you'll likely clone the repository anyways, you could get this via `Git` log. Alternatively, you could get this via the GitHub [Git API](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/commits/#get-a-commit) and parse out the message field.

Answer (score 0):

You could try and include the [Commit Message Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Commit+Message+Trigger+Plugin): your job (called by the webhook) would only start if the last message includes a specific string.

You can use the plugin as is, or customize the string by [recompiling its sources](https://github.com/jenkinsci/commit-message-trigger-plugin).